# @Input() property in angular component returns empty array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have calendar component with data property decorated as `@Input():`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() data: CalendarDay[];

  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initDays();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(this.data);
    console.log(changes.data);
  }
}
```

I pass data in from another component like that:

```
<app-calendar [data]="this.calendarData"></app-calendar>
```

And passed data gets rendered by `*ngFor` in the calendar component (it renders perfectly and everything works just fine):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.date}}</div>
```

I want to parse this data first before rendering it into view and whenever i try to console.log data property within the calendar component i get strange array, its shows as empty, i can 'open' it from browser console:

[image: Result of calling: console.log(changes.data.currentValue)].

And when i try to log value like that:

```
console.log(this.data[0])
```

or

```
console.log(changes.data.currentValue[0])
```

i get `undefined` value.

Comment: Have you tried removing the initialisation from the constructor? That doesn't need to be there. You should avoid putting anything other than dependency injection in the constructor.

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve], I recommend https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete `this.data = []` from constructor, avoid change anything when you use dependecy injecton.

And use `set` and `get` for each `Input()` that you want to use in your template, it's a best practice.

```js
  private _data: CalendarDay[];

  @Input() set data(data: CalendarDay[]) {
    if(data) {
     this._data = data;
    }
  }

  get data(): CalendarDay[] {
    return this._data;
  }
```

And in your HTML you should pass it with:

```html
<app-calendar [data]="calendarData"></app-calendar>
```

In calendar component you can use with

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.date}}</div>
```